# M/S-stereo signal to mono (for monitoring)

Tags: stereo, hardware, mono, mid-side

I'm recording in M/S-stereo for radio documentaries and would like to monitor only the M-signal (where the talking usually takes place) in my headphones. Therefore I wonder if I can use a plug [like this one](http://www.reloop.com/media/catalog/product/cache/9/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/2/3/223939_Reloop_PP.png)? Or what would happen?
Thanks!
Lasse

Comment: Are you plugging your headphones into a recorder or mixer? Some description of the equipment you're using would be helpful.

Comment: Agree. If you are recording with professional equipment, you will be able to configure the monitoring chain to dematrix and monitor in mono if required. It's simply going to be an equipment choice issue.

Comment: I'm using a Marantz PMD661, a professional recorder used by journalist all over the world, but unfortunately there is no options for matrixing.

Answer (score -2):

That adapter has a mono TS plug.  This kind of plug will short the ring contact to the ground and only leave the left as signal.  But for hearing the M signal, you need L+R, namely an adapter shorting the ring contact (right signal) to the tip contact (left signal).

Comment: If I understood the OP, his recordings are MS with M on L and S on R (not matrixed). Listening only the L channel will provide the M signal.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know any plug of that kind?